# Best approach to this question using python

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

I am new to python and practicing some problems. Unable to optimize my solution for below problem.

problem statement: Encode words in sentence based on word frequency and return their **rank** and encoded value for the word.

example:
input string --> 'aaa bb ccc aaa bbb bb cc ccc ccc bb ccc bbb'

expected output --> 3|2|1|3|4|2|5|1|1|2|1|4

Explanation:- because 'aaa' came 2 times in the original string, and 'ccc' 4 times and 'bb' 3 times, hence they get ranking based on frequency. In that manner 'ccc' rank is 1, 'bb' rank is 2, 'ccc' rank is 3. Hence the result as mentioned above.

Below is my python code, but unable to optimize it. Can someone please help.

```
def testing(s):
    ht = {}
    new_strs = strs.split()
    print(new_strs)
    for i in new_strs:
        if i in ht:
            ht[i] += 1
        else:
            ht[i] = 1
    print(ht)
    
    temp = list(map(list, sorted(ht.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)))
    print(temp)

    for k,v in enumerate(temp):
        temp[k].append(k+1)
    print(temp)
    
    final = []
    for j in new_strs:
        for t in temp:
            if t[0] == j:
                final.append(str(t[2]))
    return '|'.join(final)

strs = 'aaa bb ccc aaa bbb bb cc ccc ccc bb ccc bbb'
result = testing(str)
print(result)
```

Below is the result i am getting from this code.

```
['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bb', 'cc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'bb', 'ccc', 'bbb']

{'aaa': 2, 'bb': 3, 'ccc': 4, 'bbb': 2, 'cc': 1}

[['ccc', 4], ['bb', 3], ['aaa', 2], ['bbb', 2], ['cc', 1]]

[['ccc', 4, 1], ['bb', 3, 2], ['aaa', 2, 3], ['bbb', 2, 4], ['cc', 1, 5]]

3|2|1|3|4|2|5|1|1|2|1|4
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There are some errors in your code. For instance when calling the 'testing' function you pass in an undefined variable but then reference a global variable.

Comment: Thank you @RobertBrisita for your comment. I corrected it. Can you please review my question again. I am new to stackOverflow as well, and wrote this question incorrectly earlier. I actually need to encode words based on rank. I updated my solution and need some help in optimizing it. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine through the counting.  Starting with your `for j` loop, I'm not at all sure how you think this is supposed to work.

You need to iterate through the given words in the string -- one loop, *not* nested loops.
For each word in the input, place its frequency into the result.

```
for word in new_strs:
    final.append(str(ht[word]))
print(final)
```

With that replacement, your output is:

```
['2', '3', '4', '2', '2', '3', '1', '4', '4', '3', '4', '2']
2|3|4|2|2|3|1|4|4|3|4|2
```

---

As `Robert` already pointed out, you have other errors in your code.  In particular, you passed a *type* into your function.  If you intended `str` to be a variable, *don't do that*.  When you use a Python defined name (type string) as a variable, you damage your name space, and strange things happen.

Comment: Thank you @Prune for your comment. I corrected it. Can you please review my question again. I am new to stackOverflow as well, and wrote this question incorrectly earlier. I actually need to encode words based on rank. I updated my solution and need some help in optimizing it. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: It's not proper to materially change your question after you have received correct answers.  Rather, you need to accept and answer or delete the original question, and post a new one.  This isn't unusual -- we just want to treat our members appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little convoluted but would do it.

I think this is the best way to go i.e. separate the ranking logic into a class.

```py
from collections import Counter


class Ranker:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self._item_counts = Counter(items)
        self._ranks = list(set(i[1] for i in Counter(items).most_common()))[::-1]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._ranks.index(self._item_counts[item]) + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    strs = 'aaa bb ccc aaa bbb bb cc ccc ccc bb ccc bbb aaa'.split()
    r = Ranker(strs)
    print('|'.join([str(r[s]) for s in strs]))
    # 2|2|1|2|3|2|4|1|1|2|1|3|2
```

Comment: Did you run that code and get that output? It looks like that code will count individual characters in the string instead of words split on whitespace.

Comment: I did run the code actually.  If create a Counter with a sequence it will 'count' each one

Comment: Thank you @pcauthorn for your comment. I corrected it. Can you please review my question again. I am new to stackOverflow as well, and wrote this question incorrectly earlier. I actually need to encode words based on rank. I updated my solution and need some help in optimizing it. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Oops, I missed the `.split()` at the end. Sorry for overlooking that.

Comment: Hello @BradMartsberger, can you please read my question again. Everyone is responding with wrong answer. I need to rank each word as well. Everyone is just giving me answer based on frequency only. Please help me as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @NeerajSomani Does the edit do what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you @pcauthorn. This is helpful. Sorry, about the confusion. This problem really tricked me. So, wanted everyone's thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment, instead of

```
strs = '...'  # This is a global variable

def testing(s):
    ... # Body of testing function that never references the local `s` variable
```

You should have

```
def testing(strs):
    ... # Body of testing uses `strs` as before
```

There's no reason to sort `ht.values()`, so assigning to `temp` can be taken out altogether.

As you loop through `new_strs` all you want to be doing is making a list that contains the count of the element in new_strs. This is what you stored in the `ht` dictionary. So

```
for s in new_strs:
    final.append(ht[s])
```

Now final is a list that contains the count of how many times the strings appeared in the original string. And you can return the same as you currently do.

I recommend making those little changes and seeing that it works. Then, once the function works as you intended, there is a lot that can be cleaned up.

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a regular dictionary. And you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct the `final` list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def testing(strs):
    ht = defaultdict(int)
    new_strs = strs.split()
    for s in new_strs:
         ht[s] += 1  # if `s` is not in ht, the default 0 is used.
    final = [strs(ht[s]) for s in new_strs]
    return '|'.join(final)
```

The string join method can take a generator, so it's not necessary to create the intermediate `final` variable. The last two lines can be written as one

```
return '|'.join(strs(ht[s]) for s in new_strs)
```

The collections module has a [Counter collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) That does exactly counting things in a list. You can write this function as:

```
from collections import Counter

def testing(strs):
    new_strs = strs.split()
    ht = Counter(new_strs)
    return '|'.join(str(ht[s]) for s in new_strs)
```

Comment: The last section is the same as I wrote that you didn't think worked.

Comment: @pcauthorn, can you please read my question once again. I need a solution to encode them by rank and not by only frequency of the word. Everyone is giving me wrong solution here. Let me know if i need to reframe my question in anyway, if its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This question has changed since it was originally asked. So here is a new answer.

```
def testing(strs):
    new_strs = strs.split()
    ht = Counter(new_strs)
    ranks = rank(sorted(list(dict(ht).items()), key = lambda t: t[1], reverse=True))
    ranks_dict = dict(ranks)
    return '|'.join(str(ranks_dict[s]) for s in new_strs
```

You just need the `rank` function, which takes a sorted list of tuples of (value, score) and returns a list of (value, rank)

```
def rank(tuples):
    current_score = tuples[0][1]
    current_rank = 1
    ties = 0
    ranks = []
    for tup in tuples:
        if tup[1] == current_score:
            ties += 1
        else:
            current_rank = current_rank + ties
            ties = 1
        ranks.append((tup[0], current_rank))
        current_score = tup[1]
    return ranks
```

Note that I am counting two words that appear the same number of times as having the same rank. In your example you had them as different rank, but didn't provide a way to determine which was which. I hope this is enough to get you on track.

Comment: Thank you @BradMartsberger. This is helpful. I will keep your suggestion in mind. Sorry, about the confusion.